Sharing SharePoint Lists Between Two Web Applications
I have a quick question regarding the web applications set up on a SharePoint on-premise farm solution. Specifically, I have two applications: one is configured for anonymous public access, while the other is intended for internal Active Directory (AD) users.
I would like to know if it is possible to share the same SharePoint lists between these two applications. If it is feasible, could you please explanation on how to achieve this? An example would be particularly helpful in illustrating the process.
Any suggestion will be appreciated
